# Selenium does not download file as configured

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, download

I'm trying to configure selenium to download files to my download dir, but seems like it always downloads to a different folder.

Here is the code I'm using to configure firefox webdriver:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\");
```

Yet every time I run my test, my test fails because it can't find the file and I get this on the log:

```
1505401302370   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1505401303224   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1505401303226   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon
```

Am I missing something here?

[UPDATE]

I'm using geckodriver v0.18.0 and firefox version 55.0.3

Comment: what does your console returns if you use Syso(System.getProperty("user.home"));?

Comment: C:\Users\MYUSER

Comment: and is the downloads folder already there?

Comment: Yes. Downloading to this folder works on Google Chrome, but not on Firefox

Comment: can you remove other options and try with this alone?profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\");

Comment: Same result as before.

Comment: are you using the latest browser and gecko driver?

Comment: Yes. Latest version on both

Answer (score 0):

`browser.download.dir` is just one of the capabilities that you need to set to configure a download folder. There are two others:

`browser.download.downloadDir`
`browser.download.defaultFolder`

Filling both of these, you are able to download a file using firefox/gecko as your driver to any folder that you want to. Does not forget to setup a folder without permission restriction.

Filling example in your situation:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.downloadDir", System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\");
```

Comment: Configured the 3 of them and still I'm not able to download.

Comment: Are you sure that the program are allowed to save files in that folder? Also, you can try to use an existent firefox profile (loading it as file) and configuring its dowload folder, to check if works

Comment: if you are using an outdated version of these libs, might you're with the same error that this link explains: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/236

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It works with google chrome. But somehow when I run it with firefox, it fails.

Comment: OK. @AlexanderRumanovsk, I ask you to update your question adding your Firefox Driver version, Selenium Version and how you're creating your FirefoxDriver object. I hope with this few informations I or another user will be able to help you